# how to get values of list from controller to gsp

Tags: groovy, controller, gsp

Have been trying to get values from different procedure, but no success.

**CONTROLLER:**

```
def list(){
    Student stud = new Student()
    def listStudents = stud.executeQuery("from Student")
    listStudents.each{ lisStud->

    println "email = ${lisStud.email}"
    render view:"/layouts/listOFstudents"
}
```

**Table:**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <g:each in="${lisStud}">
    <td>${lisStud.email}</td>


    </g:each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class HelloController {
def index() {
    def list = []
    list << new Person(firstName: 'John', lastName:'Doe', age:50)
    list << new Person(firstName: 'Jane', lastName:'Smith', age:45)
    list << new Person(firstName: 'Sam', lastName:'Robinson', age:47)
    [ list:list ]
}
```

}

Just Don't Render the page to any other page then index

Answer (score 1):

Controller:

```
def list(){
 Student stud = new Student()
 def listStudents = stud.executeQuery("from Student")
 def displayStudentList = []
 listStudents.each{ lisStud->
  println "email = ${lisStud.email}"
  displayStudentList += it 
 }
 [displayStudentList : displayStudentList]
}
```

Views:

list.gsp

```
<g:each in="${displayStudentList}" var="lisStud">
  <td>${lisStud.email}</td>
</g:each>
```

Comment: Thanks.This is a really a great help. was stuck from 2 days.